# python script won't divide floats

Tags: python

I'm learning python and a quick script I'm executing is dividing floats like they're integers. Below is the script I'm running (which you'll probably recognize as one that generates some fibonacci numbers and prints their successive ratios). When I execute this in python, it treats d[x] and d[x-1] as integers when dividing them, even though they are floats. So what I get out are just a bunch of integers instead of the actual decimal ratios.

Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong? I also tried adding "from __future__ import division," at the top, which didn't affect it.

```
d = [];
d.append(1.0);
d.append(1.0);
for x in range(2,15):
        d.append(d[x-2]+d[x-1]);

for x in range(0,15):
        if x==0:
                print "%d" % (d[x])
        else:
                F = float(d[x]);
                print "%d   %d" % (d[x], F/d[x-1])
```

Comment: %d formats as an integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `%f` for  floats.

```
 print "%f   %f" % (d[x], F / d[x-1])
    1.000000   1.000000
    2.000000   2.000000
    3.000000   1.500000
    5.000000   1.666667
    8.000000   1.600000
    13.000000   1.625000
    21.000000   1.615385
```

You can also use the newer style string formatting:

```
"{:f}  {:f}".format(d[x], F / d[x-1])
```

Comment: Usually I would use `%g` for floats (nicely compacts the representation) and `%s` if I don't need to pass any formatting options.